# How to associate a domain with the outlook/live so that email address from the domain can be used to create hotmail or outlook accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I have tried older ways to connect a domain so that we can create outlook/hotmail accounts with emails from our custom domain.

We have email address like `abc@mydomain.com` and need to create outlook/hotmail accounts with that email as the ID.

So far I have followed the steps described [here](https://www.techwalls.com/how-to-create-email-with-custom-domain-on-outlook-com/#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20domain.live.com,Live%20Hotmail%20for%20my%20domain.) but unable to complete the process as it seems to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I did some search about the issue you mentioned, and sounds like adding a new alias to an @outlook.com should be able to help. However, as I know, features with Outlook.com email account and custom domain are limited. Exchange Online email account can give you total control over your email domain which seems can better meet your needs. For more information:

[Outlook.com account with a personal address or custom domain can’t be added to Outlook](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/outlookcom-with-custom-domain-from-address)

[Using Outlook.com with your own domain or current email address](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/outlookcompersonaladdress.htm)

Comment: The solution describes how to get emails from different domains into outlook - POP/IMAP. That is not want I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation tho.

Comment: Sorry about these information could not be helpful to you.